# When to use a callback instead of a normal function?

Tags: java, android, function, callback

I having a hard time grasping the idea of callbacks and why the heck I would need to use them instead of a normal function.  All of the solutions I have looked at so far have talked about passing a function to another function, which is not what I want to do.

I have implemented code into my app that I don't really know it does but it works. I just wish someone could explain it for me.

**This is a fragment class**

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    public Callback callback;

    public interface Callback {
        void send(int n); // or whatever
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_entry, container, false);

        CalendarView calendarView = v.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
        calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView calendarView, int y, int m, int d) {
                callback.sendDate(d, m, y); // this is where I'm confused
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
}
```

**Then in the main activity I implement it**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyFragment.callback {
    public void send(int n) {
        // do whatever with it
    }
}
```

As you can see, the callback function is not passed to the function like the other solutions say. So why can't I use a regular function and I guess why do I need an interface for this?

Comment: Callbacks (lambda statements) are just syntactic sugar for anonymous classes.

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart care to elaborate? :)

Comment: What is the 'other' way of doing it as you are saying? Can you include an example too?

Answer (score 0):

Callback functions use when you want do when some functionality done.
For example, some function load some text from file and give you that functionality that after or before loading file completed you could do somethings, for example log the process.
Callback usually is a interface that has some methods.you can pass any class (object) that implemented the interface.In fact, what you pass to functions as callback is an object that functions knows it and know when should call which method of it.
Another good example of callback function is in asynch process that you dont know when the process would finished, you pass object (anonymous class it called if you implement just in where you wanna pass it) that implemented target interface. 
If you carious how it is done, you can debug and see the flow of program in a simple program.check out the code below

```
public class CallbackTest {

interface Callback{
    void beforeOfLoading();
    void middleOfLoading();
    void afterOfLoading();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    loadFile(new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void middleOfLoading() {
            System.out.println("Loading is running");
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeOfLoading() {
            System.out.println("Loading is not still run");
        }

        @Override
        public void afterOfLoading() {
            System.out.println("Loading finished");
        }
    });
}

public static void loadFile(Callback callback) {
    callback.beforeOfLoading();
    System.out.println("I'm gonna load some file...");
    callback.middleOfLoading();
    System.out.println("I'm still loading...");
    System.out.println("file loaded");
    callback.afterOfLoading();
}
```

output :

```
Loading is not still run
I'm gonna load some file...
Loading is running
I'm still loading...
file loaded
Loading finished
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. What I'm confused about is what's the difference between this and and calling regular functions? What could'nt yuo just call `loadFile` and then call `beforeOfLoading` from `loadFile`?

Comment: the difference is that you dont always access to main function code, beside, the function give you a way to do something in lifecycle of function code.